# Is it illegal to use a proxy chain in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, internet, privacy

As you are all aware about the whole Facebook fiasco.... I am now wanting to be as anonymous as I can online, one method I found was to use a proxy chain. I am just wondering if it is legal in the UK before I try to set one up :) Bearing in mind that this will not be used for any illegal purposes such as: hacking, torrenting files illegally, streaming films illegally

It's purely for normal web browsing but hopefully more secure

Furthermore if it’s like this hen it’s very similar to using a tor browser or onion tor?

Another thing I have heard is that by using a tool like this your ISP is likely to cut/slow down your internet, any truth to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot answer the legal part to your question. Proxy chains are inherently slower than direct connections.

Comment: Do you know who can answer my question then? I am wanting to be sure before I go an use something like this. Also, any knowledge of the question about ISP?

Comment: May I then ask for a moderator to migrate this question then please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not illegal in UK to use proxies.

No, it is not like the tor concept.

No, the ISP does not slow you down (they mostly throttle detectable p2p connections), but if you use public proxies, many of them will be unacceptably slow.

Note: for things like facebook, a proxy is utterly useless. You already donated your private data to them, there's nothing to hide.

Comment: Alright thank you, I already know my Facebook data has been donated. It’s even worse for other services. Thank you for your response

Comment: -1 because even for something like Facebook, _location anonymity_ is extremely useful at reducing the amount of data they have on you, even if you are giving out your full name and more. So not only is an anonymity tool (whether proxies, or Tor) not "utterly useless", they are in fact extremely useful.

Comment: I disagree. You have insufficient insight into how facebook internally works. Your localized IP is only relevant for security/login purposes. From a user privacy point of view, it's among the last things that matter.

Comment: If Facebook has your name and 2-3 friends they can almost certainly figure out your exact place of residency. It's not like phone-books and voting registries are private or hard to search.